# Understand the pricing of Appscript alone and not the entire GSuite for our existing GCP

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, test-framework

Pretext:
I am a tester working on a project where we are migrating from Spark in GCP to BigQuery
I want to create a testing framework in mine with some features similar to Robot framework. 
I found Google App Script that I believe is Apt for my job.

Problem:
It looks like we have not taken the GSuite and the management might not want to buy the entire GSuite for testing.

What I am looking for:
I want to understand if there is anyway I can use the app script with minimum cost to the company or if there is any scripting that supports GCP.

Current solution:
I have connected to GCP using Shell and Python but I am looking for a google tool itself. The whole project is moving into GCP, would be nice if the testing happens in Google tools as well. I have tried making a testing framework in BigQuery as well but it does not have everything I need to make usage simple.

Answer (score 1):

### You can use Apps Script for free

The difference between a free (Consumer) account and different paid accounts is the amount of [quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) you have.

Also, for certain APIs or the use of a service account you need a GSuite domain, which is not free (you can use for most G Suite
Basic).

But for most applications you can use the free consumer account.

More information about

- [GSuite Domains](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6069226?hl=en)
- [Different types of account](https://support.google.com/a/thread/6046148?hl=en)